# Do changes in Gnome "Tweaks" require reboot to come into effect?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

Title says it all...

When I change a setting in the Gnome "Tweaks" tool, they do not come into effect; will reboot / re-login later to see if that helps; for now: frustrating!

- for instance the "**mouse click emulation**" (from 2-finger-[not a bug, it’s a feature](https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/) back to area).
- while changing the (static) **number of workspaces** seems to be working instantly.

<sub>... transitioning from Unity :( to Gnome...</sub>

Comment: No they should be instantaneous! So what did you change that didn't take effect immediately?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen (and @pomsky) - for instance the "mouse click emulation" (from 2-finger-[not a bug, it’s a feature](https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/) back to area).

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Add that to the question, otherwise it looks too-broad/unclear. Just try restarting the GNOME shell by <Alt>F2 then "r" and <Enter>.

Comment: in contrast, I think that changing the (static) number of workspaces works instantly...

Comment: That is instantaneous as I have used that so trying restart should just be a glitch

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen will report back after restart (in a few hours); preliminary hunch: **VirtualBox** is running (with Win10 as Guest); maybe it's blocking the change somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a setting immediately takes effect or not depends. In many cases, a setting immediately takes effect. In other cases, you may need to log out and then log back in for the setting to take effect. None of the settings in gnome-tweaks should require you to reboot, however. Logging out and then back again is enough. Sometimes, it might be sufficient to restart gnome shell (i.e. press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd>). The latter only works if you are running Gnome Shell on Xorg, but not if you run Gnome Shell on Wayland. Xorg is the default for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: "reboot" = re-login :)

Comment: re-login did the trick.